# Quantify the effect of experimental variation in the number of categories for a survey question?

Tags: categorical-data, experiment-design, survey, ordered-logit

I have data from a survey experiment that looks into respondents' preferences on a bioethical issue prenatal genetic diagnosis (PGD). Half of the respondents were asked to chose one of three options that were debated in parliament (complete ban, a very restrictive regime, and a restrictive regime that was actually enacted). The other half was offered two additional options (a rather liberal regime as practiced in the UK, and a very liberal regime as practiced in Belgium).

[image]

The result shows that extending the choice set produces a majority that would prefer a more liberal regime than the current law. I think the decline amongst the 'complete ban' and more importantly the 'very restrictive' category also suggests some sort of anchoring effect. What I'm looking for is a measure that would quantify the size of the effect. I was thinking of Goodman and Kruskal's Gamma or ordinal logistic regression, but I'm not sure if either adequately reflects the fact that members of the first group by design simply cannot chose the more liberal options.